# How do I type the result of calling genMockFromModule when writing a manual mock in Jest?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

Here is how my directory `orders` looks. I want to test a function that is in `orders/helpers` using a manual Jest mock.

```
orders
  __mocks__
    helpers.ts
  __tests__
    orders.ts
  helpers.ts
  orders.ts
```

In `orders/helpers.ts` I am exporting a simple function:

```
export const addIdToOrder = (order: Omit<NewOrderState, 'id'>): Order =>
  ({
    ...order,
    id: v4(),
  } as Order);
```

In `orders/__tests__/orders.ts` I can mock the module `orders/helpers` as follows:

```
const MOCK_ID = 'test-id-1234';
// mock addIdToOrder so we can have a deterministic id in tests
jest.mock('../helpers', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  addIdToOrder: (order: Omit<NewOrderState, 'id'>): Order =>
    ({
      ...order,
      id: MOCK_ID,
    } as Order),
}));
```

However, now I need to add another test file, and it will also need to mock this function from `orders/helper`, so I add the `orders/__mocks__/helpers` and try to define the mock there.
This is what I have so far:

```
const helpers = jest.genMockFromModule('../helpers');

export const MOCK_ID = 'test-id-09e26f6a-48cc-4754-bb54-22043adbe2ea';

helpers.addIdToOrder = (order: Omit<NewOrderState, 'id'>): Order =>
  ({
    ...order,
    id: MOCK_ID,
  } as Order);
```

There is an error there on `helpers.addToOrder` which is:

> Error:(8, 1) TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.

How do I type `helpers`? Can I do something like `import * as helpers from '../helpers'` and then somehow get the type of the exported object from that module? How do I do that?

Right now I am typing helpers as `any`, this removes all the TS errors, but would like to not do this.

Answer (score 4):

You can capture the type with the `typeof` keyword.

```
import * as helpers from '../helpers'

type HelpersType = typeof helpers;
const helpers = jest.genMockFromModule<HelpersType>('../helpers');
```